# Windows Installer Error Messages

Tags: windows, installation

I wrote an OLEDB program and now I want to Create install a msi Setup file, but at the time of rebuilding the following error.
Error : [Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6hnY.png)The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. the error code is 2330

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 installed product is broken somewhere - the error dialog indicates that it is attempting to self-repair but cannot access the original install source or its files. I suggest uninstalling VS 2015 Community and re-installing (because repair cannot fix it, as shown by the dialog).

Answer (score 0):

### Debugging

I am not sure what is wrong. However,

- Does this **self-repair** start when you build your own MSI in Visual Studio? It is not quite clear from the image. I would try to enable logging as explained below to debug this. Some further questions first.
- Did you install from a **network share** (UNC path) that is no longer available or temporarily offline? Or did you install Visual Studio 2015 off a **mapped drive** at some point, and the drive is no longer mapped? Can you map it? Maybe it is a machine that is switched off? See below for a script to see what the source paths point to (what potential server share may be missing).
- Did you perhaps install Visual Studio with **a different user account** than the one you are now logged in with?
- Did you try to disable any **security software** running on the box to see if this prevents the repair (should stop any file blocking that can trigger repair)?
- Is that an **Arabic machine**? The characters in the bottom right corner seems to indicate this. I suppose this could complicate things - a complex right to left language could surely be vulnerable to weird bugs.

Your error number matches the following error message: `2330: Error getting file attributes` - an error I have seen in relation to such scenarios and also on systems suffering disk errors! **Check your disk for errors please**. There could also be some other obscure problem that we rarely see.

You should be able to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio 2015 - but I wouldn't do that without some debugging. Uninstall could theoretically fail as well. I am pretty sure it should work though - as Phil has already suggested.

---

### Easy Fix?

**How about installing Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition side-by-side instead? I think this will work.** You may not need to uninstall 2015 either - though it is probably a good idea to do so - to "start fresh". Microsoft stuff always seems to find new ways to cause you lost time.

Though unlikely to help, you can also try to run this tool to check if something is wrong with MSI itself: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971187. There are many such things you could try, but I don't think they would help.

Come to think of it - did you recently perform a system restore?

---

### Logging the Self-Repair

The easiest way to get a log file for your self-repair is to enable logging globally on the machine (I like automatic logging on permanently, many people don't for performance reasons).

See [installsite.org on logging](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) (section "*Globally for all setups on a machine*") for how to do this. Implement the registry changes as explained and then trigger the Visual Studio 2015 self-repair again. Find the log file in the TMP folder with a random name (sort by change date to get the log to the top of the list). Search in the log for "**value 3**" (these are error messages) and see what it says. It should give you an indication of what file fails to load.

---

For the record: In the **event log**, you could try to determine what specific component is causing the self-repair problem. You can find some pointers on how to do this on [**installsite.org**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1037.htm).

---

### Source Paths

This may not be very helpful, but I'll leave it in since I wrote it already.

As stated above it isn't impossible that the source path for Visual Studio 2015 is missing or inaccessible (the location where the original install ran from - possibly a network share location).

To find out where you originally installed from you can find the source installation paths for all products with "visual studio" in their installation name by using this script:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set output = fso.CreateTextFile("msiinfo.csv", True)
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

On Error Resume Next ' we ignore all errors

output.writeline ("Name, InstallSource")

For Each product In installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7)

   name = product.InstallProperty("ProductName")
   installsource = product.InstallProperty("InstallSource")

   ' Write only package information for "Visual Studio" packages
   If InStr(name, "Visual Studio") Then
      output.writeline ( name & ", " & installsource )
   End If

Next

output.Close
```

**Usage**:

- Put the above script in a `*.vbs file` on your desktop and run it.
- Output will be to `msiinfo.csv` on your desktop - the operation should be very quick (seconds).
- Open this output file in Excel or equivalent spreadsheet tool. You can also open it with Notepad.
- **Look for the installation source path for your Visual Studio installation. See if you can map it or bring it online** (if it is a network path).

---